# HTML - Certain <p> tags are wrapping, but others aren't - Why?

Tags: html

all,

I've recently begun the process of learning HTML--by "recently," I literally mean "yesterday," so I have practically no experience with the language. I'm writing an HTML document in which some `<p>` tags contain body paragraphs and others contain footnotes; I'm using id attributes to distinguish between the two, and I've run into an odd problem that I'm not sure how to fix.

For some reason, the `<p>` tags which contain body paragraphs are wrapping to fit the browser window when I open the document in Google Chrome, but the `<p>` tags which contain footnotes are not. Here are the two attributes' definitions in the internal CSS:

```
<style>
<!-- [definitions of a bunch of other style elements] -->
#bodytext {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 168%;
    text-align: center;
}
#footnote {
    color: #a1e20b;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 120%;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

I see no difference between the style definition for the "bodytext" id and the style definition for the "footnote" id that would cause the discrepancy I'm seeing in the output. Can anyone please explain this?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the tag that has the 'footnote' `ID` ? Give us your `HTML` code.

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow! Can you please add your html

Comment: It's either something to do with the paragraphs (which we can't see) or some other style rules (which we can't see). You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your CSS *is* invalid so the first rule won't apply at all, but that won't affect wrapping.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've discovered the source of my issue--I mistakenly used the `<pre>` tag for my footnotes, which displays line breaks (or, in my case, lack thereof) and other extra whitespace in its output, as opposed to the `<p>` tag, which does not.